# Moving Right-Side Content to Left using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Twitter Bootstrap framework to layout my page.  I have this content:

```
<div class="clearfix row">
   <div class="span4">..</div>
   <div class="span4">..</div>
   <div class="span4">Right Content</div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is move the content labelled "Right Content" above the other content when in phone view.  I know the complexities of this without using JavaScript, but is there a way to do that in Twitter Bootstrap, either through CSS or JS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you want to do, presuming you only have the three columns in the one row div.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4 pull-right">Right Content</div>
        <div class="span4">..</div>
        <div class="span4">..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See my sample [here](http://codepen.io/peiche/pen/Dmfsx).